# Issue selecting SQL records in order of priority

Tags: sql, case

I have a SQL Server query where one address type can have multiple location names but I need to bring just one location depending on the type.  The priority is:
If the AddressType = Facility, then return that LocationName.  In the record below I would only bring back Orlando.

```
    LocationName   AddressType  ID
    Orlando        Facility     123
    Phoenix        Billing      345
    LA             Office       678
```

If there is no AddressType = Facility, but there is one for Office, then return that location.  In the record below it would only bring back LA.

```
    Location       AddressType    ID
    Phoenix        Billing        345
    LA             Office         678
```

If the AddressType equals Billing only, then the location will be null.  In the record below it would be null:

```
    Location       AddressType   ID
    Phoenix        Billing      345
```

I tried using a Case statement:

```
    select id, location, addresstype,
    CASE when addresstype = 'Facility' then 1
         when addresstype = 'Office' then 2
         when addresstype = 'Billing' then 3 end as addresstype_row_num
         into #test t
         from table
```

From this I created another query to select the minimum addresstype_row_num:

```
    select *
    from t
    where addresstype_row_num = (select (min addresstype_row_num)
                                 from t2
                                 where t.id = t2.id)
```

However, this took too long and was also returning something of a Cartesian join.  Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: temp table requires you re-write out all the records.  Temp tales should be avoided for larger data sets.  You could just use a nested sub select for what you are doing and this would be much quicker.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you're suggesting?

Comment: I can not test the validity of my syntax right now but I can post an answer for you to tweek the syntax if I make a mistake.  Example coming up.  It may vary depending on your sql platform but most likely will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select id, location, addresstype,
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by location
                                order by (case when addresstype = 'Facility' then 1
                                               when addresstype = 'Office' then 2
                                               when addresstype = 'Billing' then 3
                                          end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The `case` can be a bit cumbersome.  One method around it is to use `charindex()`:

```
select id, location, addresstype,
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by location
                                order by charindex(addresstype, 'Facility,Office,Billing')
                               ) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  This imposes restrictions on the facility names (as written).  They can't overlap.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, location, addresstype, min(addresstype_row_num) as addresstype
from 
( 
select id, location, addresstype,
CASE when addresstype = 'Facility' then 1
     when addresstype = 'Office' then 2
     when addresstype = 'Billing' then 3 end as addresstype_row_num
     from table
) x 
group by id, location, addresstype
```

-- ## (skip the temp table)

Comment: single command doing everything avoiding a temp table is faster.  Not exactly sure from what you requested if I am answering what you are asking for.  But this type of sql is optimized for Sql.  You may need to tweek the code to get the exact business rules you are looking for.